# Encoding categorical variables that do not have a rank/order for classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, categorical-data

I have primarily worked with classification problems that have numerical features size, height, weight, distance, times, bag of words/tf-idf, so on.  However, I am starting to consider working with more datasets that has categorical features. Examples of such features are race, genre (book or movie), color, shape, city name, school, etc. If I had a categorical variable called length that had the levels small, medium, large, it makes sense to recode that as 1, 2, 3 since there is already some hierarchy or order present. However, I am confused about encoding variables that do not have a natural translation to a numerical scale or already have an intrinsic sense of order.

With something like color, imagine the options are red, green, and blue. It does not make sense for red to be 1, green to be 2, and blue to be 3, because that means that red is technically "closer" to green than blue and what does it mean in this case for color to be ranked or have distance? Similarly, imagine we have a simplified list of genres (romance, comedy, drama, scifi, action). If I encode that as romance - 1, comedy - 2, drama - 3, scifi - 4, action - 5, that means in this representation romance is "closer" or more similar to comedy than drama, which really does not make sense. I feel by doing this, we're artificially creating structure and meaning that is not already present.

If you think that encoding in this manner is totally acceptable, I would love to be proved wrong (it would be much more convenient and simple to work with) -- please just explain why. If my interpretation is correct, can you explain how I can address this? What are examples of things that you have done (or commonly accepted practices)? I realize that binary variables are fairly straightforward with the examples above, but not necessarily if I have significantly more options. Note: I primarily work with Python, Pandas, and Sklearn for ML. If you suggest other tools that can help with this, let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You can use [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to convert categorical features into binary matrix like:

```
0 -> 0 0 1
1 -> 0 1 0
2 -> 1 0 0
```

If you have so many categories, this solution may not be feasible since feature matrix will become very large. In this case, what I do usually is as follows: If category distribution is not uniform, (For example, 90% of samples belong to 5 categories and others belongs to remaining 5000 categories) I convert all these 5000 categories into a new category called, OTHER. Now I have only 6 categories and can perform one hot encoding as usual.

If you have lots of categories and samples are distributed among categories equally then you can't drop categories or merge them into one.

2 - Use them as they are. If your classification can handle categorical features then you can use them directly. I assume DecisionTrees can work on both numerical and categorical data.

3 - Convert into numerical feature. This is not possible most of the time. Let's say your feature values are NORTH, SOUTHEAST, NORTHWEST and so on. In this case, Converting them into coordinates like (0, 1) for NORTH, (1, -1) for SOUTHEAST and (-1,  1) for NORTHWEST would be okay. Of course, this conversion should be logical in terms of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **one hot encoding** which is readily available through `pd.get_dummies`. The clear downside is that `# added features = # possible classes of initial feature` but there is no need to define any kind of ordering.

However, check [this](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) amazing tutorial. And if you wanna get more fancy see [Category Encoders](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/).